# CSS colors not showing in IE on Windows Phone 8.1 (work everywhere else)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, lumia

I have an issue with the CSS colours in IE on WP8.1. The device I have to hand that I'm testing with is a Lumia 635.

In short, none of the colours set in the stylesheet show at all (be it background colours, font colours, link colours, etc). They do however work on every other device I've tested this on, as well as the desktop browsers (including IE).

There seems to be no issue with the media queries or any of the rest of the CSS, it's just the colours. Here is the website, or I can post a simplified version of the code if preferred:
http://bulgarian-translation-uk.com/

Any help or suggestions where this might be coming from would be highly appreciated. I seriously doubt that it's relevant to the issue in any way, but the site running on a ColdFusion app server.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Here is some simple code that illustrates the problem - it won't even display basics like background colour, but has no problem with anything else. I've uploaded the exact same code to following test page as well:
http://bulgarian-translation-uk.com/bg/test/

```css
body {
 background-color:#000000;
}
body, .text {
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:25px;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-decoration:none;
 filter:none !important;
}
a, .text a {
 color:#0a591d;
 text-decoration:underline;
 filter:none !important;
}
.text {
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:50px;
 padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Test <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you have no style sheets or style blocks or inline styles. On the Phone see if their is a setting for the browser (IE9 I think) for Light or Dark theme.... try switching to a light theme. You should use stylesheets for coloring as the web browser may have different defaults if none are specified.

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the problem code here, not your web site which will disappear soon helping no one in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RobParsons There is a style sheet - linked to in the head just under the favicon (line 147 - bt_uk.css). In any case, I'll post a simlified version of the code in the question to make things easier.

Comment: @Rob Just uploaded some code. Unfortunately, even the bare bones like background color don't show on the Lumia I'm testing on, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the way IE for WP reads the css, but I have no clue what that could be...

Comment: @annie, I cant reproduce the issue on an WP 8.1 emulator. It must be a phone browser settings... From memory there should be settings for Theme (light or Dark). To test remove the stylesheet link (let the device render with its theme default styles)

Answer (score 0):

in the head section add

```
<style type="text/css">
html,body{height:100%}
body{color:black;background-color:white}
</style>
```